# Difference between overloading __proto__ in two similar functions

Tags: javascript

In my investigation into making *Array-like* objects, I made this function,

```
Array2 = function(){
    var out = [];
    Object.defineProperty(out, 'prototype', { value : Array2.prototype }); // store a reference
    out.__proto__ = Array2.prototype; // necessary as Array uses __proto__ and not prototype

    if(arguments.length > 1) Array.prototype.push.apply(out, arguments);   // re-implement constructor's
    else if(arguments.length === 1) out.length = arguments[0];             // argument handling behaviour

    return out;
};

// allow for normal prototyping behaviour
Array2.prototype = [];
Object.defineProperty(Array2.prototype, 'constructor', { value : Array2 });
```

and noticed that calling `Array2()` was returning the same as calling `new Array2()`, which isn't what I was expecting, so I considered a similar function for integers

```
Int = function(n){
    var out = ~~n;
    out.prototype = Int.prototype;
    out.__proto__ = Int.prototype;

    this.value = out; // added to check value when working as object

    return out;
};

Int.prototype = 0;
Int.prototype.constructor = Int;
```

this time, `Int` returns a normal instance of a Number (`__proto__` and `prototype` as for any number literal) and `new Int` returns an "Int" Object with `Empty` as `__proto__` and `undefined` for `prototype`, with the number available through `.value`, same as calling without `new`.

Why are these very similar functions acting so differently, and why is `new` resulting in the for the first one? It is most likely something obvious I've overlooked.
Only tested in Google Chrome.

Comment: Pretty sure `__proto__` shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: So, you're expecting to see the following in the console: `[]` for `Array2()`, and `[object Array2]` for `new Array2()`? (If not, I've misunderstood your question, can you clarify it?)

Comment: @RobW, yes, and more explicitly, for `new Array2()` to never show `out` because it isn't exposed with a `this`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat "Actually it is not possible to change the prototype of an instance without using the `__proto__` property." from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf#Notes

Comment: @RocketHazmat: There is no alternative to assigning to `__proto__` when you want to set the [[prototype]] of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your `Array2` function return *real* Arrays instead of only *Array-like* objects, this does not change when setting the `[[prototype]]` to an object that inherits from `Array.prototype` (altough you should not have created an array using `[]`, but a plain object using `Object.create(Array.prototype)`.

Your function `Int` has several problems.

`out` is a primitive number value, and has no properties. When assigning some, it will be implicitly casted to a `Number` object, which is discarded rightafter. The same problem with the "constructor" property on `Int.prototype = 0`.

Also, you can't use primitive values like `0` as prototype *objects*. When creating a `new Int` instance, it will inherit from the default `Object.prototype` as `0` is not of type "object". I'm not sure what happens when assigning such to the non-standard `__proto__` property, but I guess it just fails.

Use this instead:

```
function Int(n){
    var out = ~~n;
    this.valueOf = function(){ return out; };
    return out; // when not used as a constructor, return int-casted number
};

Int.prototype = Object.create(Number.prototype, {
    constructor:{value:Int}
});
```